# io.js folder disappear after rebooting

Tags: io.js

I compile io.js from sources from official github repo on lubuntu 14.10 64bit.

```
sh
./configure
sudo make install
```

I created the folder and started working with gulp. After rebooting the comp this folder dissapear.

What can cause this very strange problem?

Comment: Have you tried repeating the process? Does this happen every time?

Comment: No, not every time. Yesturday I work with gulp, and today I pointed that project folder disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install iojs. It can fetch any version

```
nvm install iojs # will install the latest
nvm install iojs-v1.5.0
nvm use iojs-v1.5.0 # use this one now
```

To know which version you are using you can put it on the prompt. For example, if you use [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) putting this on `~/.zshrc` will nicely show the version of node you are using

```
RPROMPT='%{$fg_bold[green]%}$(node -v)%{$reset_color%}'
```